# Find the line numbers at which the longest word appears in a file

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I need to find the line numbers at which the longest word in a file appears. If there are two or more different words of the same longest length, then track the first one only. I have done the tracking of the longest word but I need help finding what lines the longest word is in. This is my code that finds the longest word:

```
        while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scan2.nextLine();
            if(line.contains(longestWord)){
                longestWordList.add(longestWord);
            }
            else{
                longestWordList.add(null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you adding `null` in your `else`? And I assume that `longestWordList.add(longestWord);` should be `longestWordList.add(line);`

Comment: You need an int to track the line numbers

Comment: Are you assuming that the longest word has been found or that you'll being finding it during this process?

Comment: This code does not find the longest word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the current line number, the line number of the longest word, and the length of the longest word. For each line, split the line into an array of words by splitting on spaces and punctuation marks. You can do this with a regular expression. Then look at each word for if it is longer than the longest word. If a new longest word is found, record the current line number and record the new longest word length.

```
int lineNumLongest = 0, lineNumCurrent = 0, longestLength = 0;
while(scan2.hasNextLine()) {
    lineNumCurrent++;
    String[] words = scan2.nextLine().split("[ .?!,;:/\\\\]");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() > longestLength) {
            lineNumLongest = lineNumCurrent;
            longestLength = word.length();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't include every kind of punctuation, but it's easy to add more depending on your need. Let me know if your file contains things that don't work with this algorithm.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 10
[ .?!,;:/\]
          ^

Comment: Whoops, didn't include enough backslashes. Fixed now